# Getting a Severity: Notice in codeigniter-phpbb community

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpbb

I am using a community in Codeigniter with phpbb. I don't know why but i am getting this error

```
    A PHP Error was encountered
    Severity: Notice
    Message: Undefined index: 43
    Filename: models/forum.php
    Line Number: 287
```

Here is that function

```
    public function forumGetter() {
        $rez = $this->db->select('*')->from('phpbb_forums')->where('forum_id != 75')->where('parent_id != 75')->get();
        $ret = array();
        $foruminfo = $this->forumInfo();
        foreach ($rez->result_array() as $k=> $v) {
            $x = $v;
            $x['usercount'] = intval($foruminfo[$v['forum_id']]['usercount']);
            $ret[$v['parent_id']][] = $x;
        }
        return $ret;
    }
```

and line 287 is

```
            $x['usercount'] = intval($foruminfo[$v['forum_id']]['usercount']);
```

where i am wrong or which kind of error is this?

Comment: The error is because `$foruminfo` doesn't have a key with the value of `$v['forum_id`]` (which is `43`). In other words; `$foruminfo[43]` does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update this line:

```
$x['usercount'] = intval($foruminfo[$v['forum_id']]['usercount']);
```

To:

```
$x['usercount'] = isset($foruminfo[$v['forum_id']]) && isset($foruminfo[$v['forum_id']]['usercount']) ?
                  intval($foruminfo[$v['forum_id']]['usercount']) : 0;
```

---

The error is; you are trying to load an array value by the key `43`, i.e. `$foruminfo[$v['forum_id']][43]` and you get that error when a value doesn't exist by the specified key. So, best option is to use [isset()](http://php.net/isset) to assert before you use the key on the array.

Comment: awesome answer man. tell me one more thing.. i am also getting this error Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: usercount

Filename: bbincludes/forums.php

Line Number: 139

Comment: Show us the code from `bbincludes/forums.php Line Number: 139`